# Magento 2 - sort by price

Tags: sorting, magento2

I have a problem with a multistore site created with Magento 2.4. Right now the products from the category page and the search page are arranged by name. The options for sorting are: Alphabetical A - Z and Z - A, and by price from low to high and high to low. When I try to sort the products alphabetical everything works fine, but when I try by price it's like a random sort. I also put a custom module but the same result. Instead, if I sort them by product id or by weight it is ok.

```
if ($currentOrder) {
            if ($currentOrder == 'price_asc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'price_desc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'name_asc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('name', 'asc');
            } elseif ($currentOrder == 'name_desc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('name', 'desc');
            }
        }
```

I also put `->getStoreId(1)` after `getCollection()` but I have same the result. Edit: from what I saw instead of sort by price it's a sort by product id

Answer (score -1):

Steps to Add Magento 2 Sort by Price for Low to High & High to Low Options:

Step 1: Create registration.php file in app\code\Vendor\Extension

Step 2: Create module.xml file in app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc

Step 3: Create di.xml file in app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc

Step 4: Create Toolbar.php file in app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Catalog\Block

Step 5: Create Config.php file in app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Catalog\Model

You can refer to the details [here](https://magecomp.com/blog/add-magento-2-sort-by-price-for-low-to-high-high-to-low-options/).

Comment: I already did that. In the end the problem it was because of a custom module. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score -1):

It Work's for Magento 2.4 versions
I am Assuming you have created a custom module Vendor/module_sort

1. create di.xml file in vendor/module_sort/etc/

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
            <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
                <plugin name="Vendor_module_sort::addCustomOptions" type="Vendor\module_sort\Plugin\Model\Config" />
            </type>
            <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\module_sort\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Toolbar" />
    </config>
```

2. Create Config.php in Vendor/module_sort/plugin/Model

---

```
  <?php
    namespace Vendor\module_sort\Plugin\Model;
    
    class Config  {
    
        public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
        {
           
            unset($options['name']);
            unset($options['price']);
    
            //New sorting options
            $customOption['high_to_low'] = __( 'Price High to Low' );
            $customOption['low_to_high'] = __( 'Price Low to High' );
            $customOption['name_Z_to_A'] = __( 'Product Title:Z-A' );
            $customOption['name_A_to_Z'] = __( 'Product Title:A-Z' );
    
            // $customOption['name'] = $default_options['name'];
    
            //Merge default sorting options with custom options
            $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);
    
            return $options;
        }
    }
```

3. Create Toolbar.php in Vendor/module_sort/plugin/Catalog/Block/

---

```
 <?php
    namespace Vendor\module_sort\Plugin\Catalog\Block;
    
    class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    {
    
        /**
         * Set collection to pager
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
         * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
         */
        public function setCollection($collection)
        {
            $this->_collection = $collection;
    
            $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
    
            // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
            $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
            if ($limit) {
                $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
            }
            if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
                if (($this->getCurrentOrder()) == 'position') {
                    $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
                        $this->getCurrentOrder(),
                        $this->getCurrentDirection()
                    );
                } else {
                    if ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'high_to_low') {
                        $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
                    } elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'low_to_high') {
                        $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'asc');
                    }elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'name_Z_to_A') {
                        $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'desc');
                    }elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'name_A_to_Z') {
                        $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'asc');
                    }
                }
            }
            return $this;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).